# I have change my type to int but still got "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"

Tags: python, numpy

I have found that many solve this problem by adding astype(int) to the numpy array , and I have try it , but it didn't work. This is my code

```
print('----loading data----')
t0 = time.time()
f1 = 'D:/building/big data/not test'

def get_imlist(path):   

    return [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.jpg')]

imagePath1 = get_imlist(f1) 

test_N = len(imagePath1)
test_data = np.ones((test_N,256,256,3),dtype='float64')

def loadIMG(imagePath , number, Array):
    while number > 0:
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath[number-1])
    img = cv2.resize(img,(256,256),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img_ndarray=np.asarray(img,dtype=int)
    Array[number-1] = img_ndarray
    number = number - 1
loadIMG(imagePath1, test_N, test_data)

test_data = test_data/255


test_data.astype(int)

print('---finish loading----')
t1 = time.time()
print('time:'+ str(round((t1-t0),4))+ ' sec')

print('----start predicting----')
t2 = time.time()
#load model
autoencoder = load_model('segnet2_outputgray_v3.h5')

for i  in test_data:
    result = autoencoder.predict(test_data[i])
    a=result[0]
    ret, th1 = cv2.threshold(a, np.mean(result), 255 , 0)
    th1 = cv2.cvtColor(th1,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    imgstack = np.hstack((test_data, th1))
    cv2.imwrite('D:/building/big data/predict/'+str(i)+'.jpg', imgstack)
    i = i + 1
    
t3 = time.time()
print('----finish predicting----')
```

And the error occurs in this line

```
result = autoencoder.predict(test_data[i])
```

And the IndexError

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

And I have specifically define the dtype when  I create the numpy ones array to float64.And it itsn't working even though I change dytpe to int.

Comment: `test_data.astype(int)` makes a new array.  It does not change `test_data`.  Check it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error reads;

> arrays used as indices must be of **integer** (or boolean) type

And then you say;

> And I have specifically define the dtype when I create the numpy ones array to **float64**, so I have no idea what's going on

You have no idea what is going on???

As you stated yourself you explicitly define the dtype to be float64, well there's your problem!.

A float64 is as the name suggests a "float" and not an "int". Numpy requires an integer or array of integers as index, and will not work with float64.

Comment: sorry,but I  have still got the same error after delete it.And the error is still in that line

Comment: @楊尚峰 So what is the data type of the array that you are trying to use as an index? I can't judge that from looking at your code. You need to make sure that you are using something that Numpy allows as an index, ie. Integers or Bools.

Try doing;
```
print(i.dtype)
```
Just above the line where you try to use "i" as an index..